# Como pegar um valor de elemento html via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

[image: **inserir a descrição da imagem aqui**]

Eu quero pegar o valor "13" presente neste li class.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função querySelector do javascript, conforme abaixo

```js
var a =  document.querySelector(".pageNav-page>a");
var textoDeA = a.innerText;
console.log(textoDeA);
```

```html
<li class="pageNav-page">
  <a href="">13</a>
</li>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp